# Should an answer quote the rules of the game in question?

Tags: discussion

This question was written with MTG in mind but it could apply to any game with a clearly defined source of rules.

Should an answer always contain a direct quote from the relevant rules?

Comment: Was there a specific incident or comment that prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, your comment on my answer [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/20814/7002). I frequently don't answer questions I can't prove the answer to. In that specific instance it was late at night so I just didn't care so I answered it anyway. Given it's positive reception now I'm rethinking my normal mode of operation.

Answer (score 5):

An answer does not *need* to contain a quote from the rules, but it is a good idea even in situations where it is not necessary.

Most questions are from users who aren't interested in a breakdown of exact rules that create the end result. They just want a simple explanation of what that end result is. In this case a quote is not necessary so long as what happened can be explained. A rules quote would improve an answer but is not necessary for it meet the askers need.

If the user did need a more detailed breakdown the rules in debate a the other answer might still be of use to other users who might feel overwhelmed by the technical nature of the rules.

In a nutshell: **If you know the solution don't hesitate to answer a question because you can't find rule to quote, but if you know the relevant rule then quote it.**

Comment: For the specific case of MTG, I think it's also really important to sometimes also quote rulings from gatherer or even sometimes the basic rules, instead of only quoting the comprehensive rules. It can be really tough for people to understand the comprehensive rules when they're asking more basic questions.